# Spring-Data-JPA atomic insert with dependencies

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert Entities to a database from a scalable microservice. I tried `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` to prevent from doubled entries. The problem is, I have dependencies on my Entities.

A basic example is:

TestEntity.java

```
public class TestEntity {

    @GeneratedValue()
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String string;

    @ManyToOne
    private TestEntityParent testEntityParent;

}
```

TestEntityParent.java

```
public class TestEntityParent {

    @GeneratedValue()
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String stringTwo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "testEntityParent")
    private List<TestEntity> testEntities;

}
```

TestEnityRepository.java

```
public interface TestEnityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity,Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    TestEntity saveAndFlush(TestEntity testEntity);

    Optional<TestEntity> findByStringAndTestEntityParentStringTwo(String string, String stringTwo);

}
```

TestEntityParentRepository.java

```
public interface TestEntityParentRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntityParent, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    TestEntityParent save(TestEntityParent testEntityParent);

    Optional<TestEntityParent> findByStringTwo(String stringTwo);
}
```

AtomicDbService.java

```
@Service
public class AtomicDbService {

    @Autowired
    TestEnityRepository testEnityRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestEntityParentRepository testEntityParentRepository;

    @Transactional
    public TestEntity atomicInsert(TestEntity testEntity) {
        TestEntityParent testEntityParent = testEntityParentRepository.findByStringTwo(testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo())
                .orElse(testEntityParentRepository.save(testEntity.getTestEntityParent()));

        return testEnityRepository.findByStringAndTestEntityParentStringTwo(
                testEntity.getString(), testEntity.getTestEntityParent().getStringTwo()
        ).orElse(testEnityRepository
                .save(
                        TestEntity.builder()
                                .string(testEntity.getString())
                                .testEntityParent(testEntityParent)
                                .build()
                )
        );
    }

}
```

My test case:

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testAtomicInsert(){

        TestEntityParent testEntityParent = TestEntityParent.builder().stringTwo("testTwo").build();
        TestEntity testEntity = TestEntity.builder().string("test").testEntityParent(testEntityParent).build();

        atomicDbService.atomicInsert(testEntity);
        System.out.println(testEnityRepository.findAll());
        atomicDbService.atomicInsert(testEntity);
        System.out.println(testEnityRepository.findAll());
        atomicDbService.atomicInsert(testEntity);
        System.out.println(testEnityRepository.findAll());

        System.out.println(testEnityRepository.findAll());

    }
```

I get the following answer:

```
[TestEntity(id=2, string=test, testEntityParent=TestEntityParent(id=1, stringTwo=testTwo, testEntities=null))]
[TestEntity(id=2, string=test, testEntityParent=TestEntityParent(id=1, stringTwo=testTwo, testEntities=null)), TestEntity(id=3, string=test, testEntityParent=TestEntityParent(id=1, stringTwo=testTwo, testEntities=null))]
```

and an error:

```
query did not return a unique result: 2;
```

Without dependencies everything works fine.

**UPDATE:**

Adding `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` to the find method leads to

```
Feature not supported: "MVCC=TRUE && FOR UPDATE && JOIN"; SQL statement:
```

... same applies to

```
 @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
 @Query("SELECT e from TestEntity e join e.testEntityParent p where e.string = :string and p.stringTwo = :stringTwo ")
 Optional<TestEntity> findWhatever(@Param("string") String string, @Param("stringTwo") String stringTwo);
```

... since `for update` is always generated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it was a stupid mistake I needed to replace `orElse` with `orElseGet` and a lambda and everything worked, even without all those `@Lock`, etc - tricks.

Still I don't understand what exactly went wrong with the transactions and why.